# debugging the assembly equivalent of a c code to understand the function call

Tags: c, function, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu-registers

Just for my curiosity, I was looking on how the values passed to a function are actually operated by the called function. To make my doubt clear, I have an understanding that a compiler generates a code for a c code compiling it sequentially(Please correct if I am wrong). My doubt is how is  the parameter value accessed in the called function? I mean parameter  must be some a part of the calling function (like main() in my given example). How the compiler arrange that value passed in the calling function is same as the value accessed in the called function. To make my point clear, please look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check(int);

int main()
{
    check(9999);
}

void check(int a)
{
    int b;
    b = a;
}
```

In the above code after the execution of code, value of `b = 9999`; but how come the value of `a` in the function `check()` attain the value of `9999` at assembly level when the function `check()` is called from `main()`. Is it like parameters are stored in certain registers and accessed accordingly using those registers in the `check()`. I hope you understood my question.

Comment: Ask the compiler to output the assembly code (e.g. `gcc -fverbose-asm -S`). Notice that the compiler could optimize your `check` function to a `nop`

Comment: How parameters are passed to functions may vary (because of compiler optimizations and calling conventions). To start you may read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: Usually (depends on the OS and compiler) what is passed is the address of "a", occasionally a pedantic compiler will pass the address of a copy of "a" as its stricly a pass by value call but this is almost always optimised away.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: no, the address of `a` is not passed! since C has a call-by-value semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) depend upon the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the target processor (for your compiler).

There is a wikipage on [x86 calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). On Linux, you should read the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf). (Your `a` formal argument to `check` is passed in a register).

The compiler is allowed to [optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) your `check` to a `nop` (since its argument `a` has no observable effect)

Read also wikipage on [evaluation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy): the C programming language requires a *call-by-value* semantics.

Consider (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) compiling with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S` (perhaps also with optimizing options like `-O2`) and look inside the produced `*.s` assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gcc -S source.c` or `gcc -S source.c -O2` Both commands generates assembler code, but the 1-st command generates code without optimization, and parameters will be pass over stack, then the 2-st cammand with optimization, and parameters will be pass over registers